# Proving these two statements are equivalent in this field of characteristic $\neq 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

**Problem:** Let $K$ be a field with char$(K) \neq 2$ and let $E/K$ be a field extension. Prove the following statements are equivalent:

(i) $E/K$ is a Galois extension of degree $4$ and $Gal(E/K) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

(ii) $E = K(\alpha, \beta)$ with $\alpha, \beta \in E \setminus K$, $\alpha \cdot \beta \notin K$ and $\alpha^2, \beta^2 \in K$.

Hint: Prove the following lemma first, and then use it:

Lemma: If Char$(K) \neq 2$ and $L/K$ is a field extension of degree $2$, then $L = K(\gamma)$ with $\gamma^2 \in K$.

**Attempt:**

Proof of the lemma: Suppose char$(K) \neq 2$ and let $K \subset L$ be a field extension of degree $2$. Let $\gamma \in L \setminus K$. We wish to show $L = K(\gamma)$. We have $$ 2 = [L: K]  = [L: K(\gamma)] [K(\gamma) : K]. $$ Now $K(\gamma) \neq K$ because $\gamma \notin K$, and thus $[K(\gamma) : K] \neq 1$. It follows that $[L:K(\gamma) ] = 1$ because $2$ is prime. So $L = K(\gamma)$. I wish to show also that $\gamma^2 \in K$, but I don't know how. Where do I use that Char$(K) \neq 2$ for this?

Proof of theorem:

Suppose that we had proven the lemma.

I now wish to show $(i) \Rightarrow (ii)$. It is given that $Gal(E/K) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \cong V_4$ where $V_4$ is the Klein four group. Since $V_4$ is Abelian, every subgroup is normal. In particular, we know there exists a subgroup $H$ of order $2$. By the Galois correspondence, we know there must exist a normal (intermediate) field extension $L$ such that $$K \subset L \subset E$$ and such that $[L: K] = 2$. From the lemma, we have $L = K(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in L \setminus K$ and $\alpha^2 \in K$. Also, it is clear that $[E: L] = 2$. Again by the lemma, we may write that $E = L(\beta)$ with $\beta \in E \setminus L$ and $\beta^2 \in L$.

Now I wanted to claim that $E = K(\alpha, \beta)$. But I'm not sure how this follows from what I said previously, and also I have that $\beta^2 \in L$, while I need $\beta^2 \in K$. And the fact that $\alpha \cdot \beta \notin K$ is also not clear to me.

For the converse, $(ii) \Rightarrow (i)$ I didn't have a lot of inspiration. I wrote $$ [E: K] = [K(\alpha, \beta): K] = [K(\alpha)(\beta): K(\alpha] [K(\alpha):K]. $$

From this I still need to prove somehow that $K \subset E$ is a Galois extension of degree $4$. I think one can argue the isomorphism by claiming there are only two groups of order $4$, and then appealing to order of subgroups perhaps, so that it must be the Klein four group.

Help with finishing this problem is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For the proof of the lemma, you realized that $K[\gamma]=L$, since its degree is $2$, $\gamma^2=a\gamma+b$, this implies that $(\gamma-{a\over 2})^2=c-{a^2\over 4}$, write $c=\gamma-{a\over 2}, K[c]=K[\gamma]$.

Proof of the theorem. $Gal(E/K)$ is the product of two groups $I,J$ which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2$, as you have remarked, let $L^I$ the subfield of $L$ fixed by $I$, $[L^I:K]=2$, we can write $L^I=K(\alpha), L^J=K(\beta), \alpha^2,\beta^2\in K$. Remark that if $x\in L^I\cap L^J$, $x$ is fixed by $I$ and $J$, this implies that $x\in K$. You deduce that $[K(\alpha,\beta):K]=[K(\alpha,\beta):K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):K]$, $[K(\alpha,\beta):K(\alpha)]=1$ implies that $\beta\in K(\alpha)$ and $L^J\subset L^I$ contradiction, you deduce that $ [K(\alpha,\beta):K(\alpha)]=2$, and $K(\alpha,\beta)=L$.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how you prove that $\gamma^2 \in K$. You first introduce $a, b$ , then you work with $c$. I see that $K[c] = K[\gamma]$ but how does this imply $\gamma^2 \in K$?

Comment: It is not $\gamma^2\in K,$ but $(\gamma-{a\over 2})^2\in K$, you can replace $\gamma$ by $\gamma-{a\over 2}$, or start by $K[\gamma']=L$ and call $\gamma=\gamma'-{a\over 2}$,...

Comment: @Kamil   Perhaps you should take a look at Kummer's theory (in any textbook). The most recent answer to your kind of question on RG is probably here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2900791/300700

Answer (score 1):

You'll use $char(K) \neq 2$ to invoke primitive element theorem for the proof of the lemma :

One has an intermediate extension $F$ of degree 2 of $K$. Since $char(K) \neq 2$, $F / K$ is a separable extension, hence there is a primitive element, say $\gamma$, ie $F = K(\gamma)$.

Now we can use the solution of Tsemo Aristide :

There are $a, b \in K$ such that $\gamma^2 = a \gamma + b$.

Set $\alpha : = \gamma - \frac{a}{2}$. Obviously, $K(\alpha) = K(\gamma)$ hence $\alpha$ is also a primitive element of $F$. Moreover,

$$\alpha^2 = (\gamma - \frac{a}{2})^2 = \gamma^2 - a\gamma + \frac{a^2}{4} = b + \frac{a^2}{4} \in K$$